# Thymeleaf rendering

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

Using jsp we can render html elements as

```
<c:set var="size" value="0" />
<c:forEach items="${fields}" var="field" varStatus="status">

    <c:if="${status.first}">
        <div class="row">
    </c:if>

    <c:set var="size" value="${size + field.size}" />
    <c:if="${size > 12}">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <c:set var="size" value="${field.size}" />
    </c:if>

    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/field.jsp" >
        <jsp:param name="field" value="${field}"/>
    </jsp:include>  

    <c:if="${status.last}">
        </div>
    </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

Here i am building htmls input elements in `<div class="row"></div>` based on the size of fields(size 6 becomes span6). If my fields list has 4 elements with size as 6, 3, 8 and 4, it will render the html as

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
     <input />
  <div>
  <div class="span3">
     <input />
   <div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
     <input />
  <div>
  <div class="span4">
     <input />
   <div>
</div>
```

I tried to convert the first few sections to thymeleaf as

```
<th:block th:with="size=0">
    <th:block th:each="field, iterStat : ${fields}">
        <th:block if="${iterStat.index == 0}">  
            <div class="row">
        </th:block> 
            <th:block if="${iterStat.index == (#lists.size(${fields}) - 1)}">   
            </div>
        </th:block>
    </th:block> 
</th:block>
```

But thymeleaf cannot render it, since the div tag `<div class="row">` is not closed within the `<th:block>` where it is started.
Is there any way to convert the above jsp code to thymeleaf.

I am using thymeleaf 2.0.17 and spring3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I were you I would use the following code which would achieve separation of concerns and would also achieve what you are trying to do:

First create a class which takes care of creating sublists from a list of sizes.
For ease of use of this class withing Thymeleaf, we can make this class a Spring bean.
The following is a crude piece of code that would get that job done:

```
@Component
public class BoostrapUtility {

   public List<List<Integer>> createSubLists(Collection<Integer> sizeList) {
        final List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();

        final int maxSize = 12;
        int rowSize = 0;
        List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer size : sizeList) {
            if(rowSize + size <= maxSize) {
                subList.add(size);
                rowSize += size;
            }
            else {
                results.add(subList);
                subList = new ArrayList<>();
                subList.add(size);
                rowSize = size;
            }
        }
        if(!subList.isEmpty()) {
            results.add(subList);
        }

        return results;
   }
}
```

Then your Thymeleaf code would look something like :

```
<div class="row" th:each="subLists : ${@boostrapUtility.createSubLists(${fields})}">
   <div th:class="span+${field}" th:each="field : ${subLists}">
     <!-- whatever in here -->
   </div>
</div>
```